# Bootstrap modals don't show up properly SOMETIMES?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've created a modal for my site using Bootstrap v3.3.2 but sometimes it doesn't appear properly when triggered. Specifically the modal itself shows up but the content in it doesn't. It looks empty like I can see only the modal background. This problem randomly happens and can be solved after a page refresh. BTW I don't want this to happen to my users. It ruins their experience. Any ideas? Is it related to where stylesheets and scripts are located? I simply put all css links in `<head>` and put all scripts just before `</body>`. Thank you good guys.

Comment: can i look at code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer for it. I was also having the same issue today, Now my model is not losing data anymore.

What I did is I had kept modal(i.e myModal) somewhere else also where I do not need.so i commented first and then removed after successful testing.

Try it ,If same case on your then awesome..

Comment: Is it OK to put the modal div at the bottom of html? Just before the closing </body> tag.

Comment: It may affect, infact always try to place a modal’s  code in a top-level position in your document to avoid other components affecting the modal’s appearance and/or functionality.